# Diagrams symbols in UML , OOAD

Tags: design-patterns, uml, ooad

I have seen many symbols, notations related to UML and OOA&D. Most of the times those symbols don't have any labels so I am not able to understand what they are. For example, we have symbol for `Generalization` , `Realization`, `Uses` etc.

Is there any book , resource which depicts commonly used symbols and their meaning?

Comment: With your rep you should know that this is OT. Go Google. It has many recommendations.  https://www.uml-diagrams.org is a quick start too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A *generalization* is an inheritance in the general sense of the term. From the norm :

> a taxonomic relationship between a more general Classifier and a more specific Classifier. Each instance of the specific Classifier is also an instance of the general Classifier. The specific Classifier inherits the features
>   of the more general Classifier.

- A *realization* is for instance a specialization of inheritance, an inheritance between a class and an interface. More globally it is, from the norm :

> a specialized Abstraction relationship between two sets of model Elements, one representing a specification (the supplier) and the other represents an implementation of the latter (the client). Realization can be used to model stepwise refinement, optimizations, transformations, templates, model synthesis, framework composition, etc.

- Uses ? You mean Use cases ?

> Is there any book , resource which depicts commonly used symbols and their meaning?

There is only one source you can trust on without any doubt : the [OMG UML documentation](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) where UML is defined, so typically the [superstructure](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF).

Warning for instance with Wikipedia which is *not* interested by saying the 'truth' but only by duplicating referenced sources independently of their content (I unfortunately known what I mean, by experience about my Tool BoUML).

The problem with normative documents is that they are rapidly indigestible. A tutorial can therefore help from time to time ... before returning to the norm to be certain of what one reads.